# Word similar to "parse-word", but for pushing integers onto the stack

Tags: forth, gforth

I would like to implement a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for setting port numbers on a socket object.

I would like the DSL to follow this API for setting the host port number:

```
host: 8080
```

If this were a string operation (such as `host: localhost`) I could use `parse-word`. That's less than ideal though, since Forth is very good at parsing numbers, and re-inventing the wheel is a bad thing.

Are there any standard words in Forth that take the first item on the input string, parse it to a number and push it on the stack?

Comment: I am not sure if I will be able to answer your question, but can you have a look at *[An infix syntax for Forth](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/euroforth/ef08/papers/haley.pdf)* by Andrew Haley (Firefox wasn't too happy displaying it, but it worked fine saving it and using a normal PDF reader)?

Comment: Other input, from *[ForthMacro](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForthMacro)*: "This is also used by words like create and ." and ['] to parse the input stream for strings and symbols, allowing Forth to use syntaxes other than postfix. This can be handy for creating DomainSpecificLanguages (such as infix mathematical expressions or state diagrams)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>NUMBER` is an ANS word (in CORE) that turns strings into numbers, but it's cumbersome to use.  Your Forth probably has a more flexible variant.  Your Forth probably also supports syntax like `#16` `$10` `%10000`, which all evaluate to 16, regardless of `BASE`.  So one way to do this:

```
: parse-num ( "number" -- n | d | r )  parse-word evaluate ;
```

Or with `>NUMBER`, and only returning a single-cell number:

```
: parse-num ( "number" -- n )
  0. parse-word >number ( d c-addr u )
    abort" not a number" drop
    abort" double received where single-cell number expected" ;
```

Which aborts if the returned string isn't the empty string that would result if the entire output of `PARSE-WORD` was converted into a number, or if the high bits of the double aren't 0, which would be the case if a number not representable by a cell were entered.  (NB. `>NUMBER` doesn't handle double-number syntax either.  It will stop parsing `1.` at the dot.  It doesn't even handle negative numbers.)

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for.